# How to use LuaDoc with LuaForWindows

Tags: documentation, lua, documentation-generation, luadoc

The question is all in the title : how to use LuaDoc with LuaForWindows ?

In my Lua installation, I have a luadoc_start.bat but the command windows closes as soon as it opens. 
From there I don't know what else can I do.

Any help ?
Thanks

Comment: Open command prompt/powershell; `luadoc_start.bat filename.lua`

Comment: Tanks, I get a doc file to properly generate but how to do it for the whole project ? I understand there is a -d argument but I am not sure how to use it, none of my tries where successful.

Comment: You mean iterating through all lua files?

Comment: i've installed the lua and i get luadoc_start but when i run it i get an error is there any dependency needed or any additional work should i do ?

Comment: How did you get your hands on that file? I've installed everything with luarocks but I simply don't get how to run this thing ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203830/how-to-run-luadoc )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For using `luadoc` in **Lua For Windows**, the command is like this:

```
luadoc_start.bat path\to\lua\file\name.lua
```

which is to be done in either the command prompt window, or powershell.

> I get a doc file to properly generate **but how to do it for the whole project**? I understand there is a -d argument but I am not sure how to use it, none of my tries where successful.

For this task, you'll need to write a shell script. Here's a small [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) script.

```ps1
$files = Get-ChildItem .\
foreach( $file in $files ) {
    luadoc_start.bat "$file"
}
```

Where, you have to `cd` to the `path\to\lua\file` directory and run this `PS1` file.

Comment: So, the ExecutionPolicy things was a bit of a mess, but I get it to work ! I am surprised LuaDoc has no built-in ways to generate the doc for a whole hyerarchie but anyway thanks all.

Comment: Any chance you can help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203830/how-to-run-luadoc) ?

Answer (score 1):

Just append `pause` line to `luadoc_start.bat` and you will see help screen.