# Error generating documentation for lua

Tags: lua, documentation-generation, luadoc

i'm trying to generate documentation for my `lua` project

i have my `lua` installation folder and within it i have `luafilesystem` and `lualogging` but when i try to generate doc using `luadoc-start.bat` i get an error saying `lfs` module not found

i think `lfs` means `luafilesystem`

so my question is how to install and configure the dependency for `luadoc` tool?

i'm using this tool as this post saying [How to use LuaDoc with LuaForWindows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033719/how-to-use-luadoc-with-luaforwindows)

i wonder if this is the right way or not ?

and i see installation instruction from [manual](http://keplerproject.github.io/luadoc/manual.html) but it's look ambiguous for me

thanks

Comment: Please post where you have installed luafilesystem (lfs) and what is your Lua path.

Comment: i've installed lua using lua for windows.exe that excutable setup every things for so i have lua installation in C:\Program Files (x86)\lua\5.1 and i installed lfs in the same directory manually and i tried to install it using luarocks but it's doesnt work also i get an error too

Comment: my problem is that i'm making corona game and i want to generate docs for my code and i haven't did any thing with lua installation

Comment: From a console, start the Lua interactive interpreter and do `require "lfs"`. What happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a console, start the Lua interactive interpreter and do require "lfs". If it says "module lfs not found" then your installation is incorrect. Create a Lua script that just prints hello and save it in a folder of your choice, name the file "mytest.Lua". From a Wondows console, CD to that folder and start Lua and require "mytest". If that works, copy the lfs files to the same folder and try `require "lfs"`. If it works, you can now run the luadoc from that folder. If it doesn't, you are missing some lfs files such as a DLL.

Note: lfs is a Lua module that is provided as a DLL; there is no .lua file for it. When you do `require "lfs"`, Lua will first try the to find any module of given name that matches one of the patterns in `package.path` (try `print(package.path)`) then if no matches, it will do same for all patterns in `package.cpath`. Pay close attention to the error message you get once you type the require lfs command: it should indicate which patterns it tried, in what folders.

Comment: it's works but luafile system not a lua module so how i will require it ?

Comment: and lua logging and lfs the dependency for lua doc compatible with lua 5.1 how i can generate docs for lua 5.2?

Comment: @tony What makes you say you can't use Lua 5.1 to generate docs for Lua 5.2?

Comment: i thought that i must use same version thx @scholli for you r help im gonna try it

Comment: so i did as what u said with lua 5.2 and i also installed exe for lua 5.1 it's seems work now in both version but what i get is error atempt to call global module a nil value

Comment: with each version i get that error in different file but i both cases the error on the line that contain for ex:module("luadoc") so i got that error here?

Comment: @Tony this is a Q&A forum so please try to add facts to your question rather than spread them throughout a slew of comments. You can put a line "*Update 1:*" in your question, with additional info based on what people ask. Then you just put a comment "@whoever see update 1". This way there is one place to look for the all the facts related to a question.

Comment: @Tony Btw I don't understand your last comment, please clarify by updating your post as explained. And please pay attention to punctuation, your text is hard to understand, this may decrease how many people bother to answer your question (why would someone answer if you can't be bothered to explain clearly and format properly your question?)

Comment: thanks @schollii but i can't update my question because you solution works for me but i get another error i will post another question for that